# crash while calling CMemFile::Detach()

Tags: file-io, crash

I am observing a crash while calling the CMemFile::Detach() function

The exception with the call stack is as below

kernel32!RaiseException+53     e06d7363     00000001     00000003
msvcrt!_CxxThrowException+36     0103bb7c     7f0f6eac     00d8bf68
mfc42u!AfxThrowFileException+61     00000009     ffffffff     00000000
mfc42u!CMemFile::Seek+42     fffff159     00000001     00000194
mfc42u!CArchive::Flush+26     0103bbf0     7f02d05a     00d32388
mfc42u!CArchive::Close+a

This is occuring after i deserialize an object.

The versionable schema for the object seems to be correct.

Any idea as to wat may cause this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function AfxThrowFileException has three parameters. The first parameter denotes the cause. In your case this is CFileException::badSeek. This can happen if the CMemFile pointer is changed without notifying the CArchive object. It is better to use the CArchive object to change the file pointer.